# Is + a disallowed charecter in URLs?

Tags: codeigniter, url, uri, codeigniter-3

What is disallowed in the following URL?

```
http://myPortfolio/Showcase/Kimber+Tisdale+Photography
```

I am getting **The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.** error message. Where as as far as I understand `+` is allowed, isn't it?

Reference: [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an allowed character but not in the way you are using it. It is allowed in the query string part of a url, not in the url path names.

If you are just seperating words, it is more usual to use a hyphen or an underscore, or %20 for a space. You can use CI's url helper to encode strings for you:

```
$title = 'Kimber Tisdale Photography';
$url_title = url_title($title, '-');
// ouptut kimber-tisdale-photography
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#url_title

Answer (score 0):

The `+` is allowed in URI paths.

You can check it yourself:

1. Visit the [URI standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).
2. Check which characters are allowed in the [Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) component.
3. Note that every non-empty path may contain characters from the `segment` set.
4. Note that the `segment` set consists of characters from the `pchar` set.
5. Note that the `pchar` set contains characters from the `sub-delims` set.
6. And `sub-delims` is defined to consist of:

> "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

As you can see, the `+` is listed here.

([See my list of all allowed characters in URI paths](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/91211/17633).)

A prominent example of `+` in the path of HTTP(S) URIs are Google Plus profiles, e.g.:

[`https://plus.google.com/+MattCutts`](https://plus.google.com/+MattCutts)